# Blinking is off - Still cursor blinking - ConEmu and Cmder

Tags: conemu, cmder

I have this issue where cursor is constantly blinking in Cmder with windows 10 . If I switch off blinking from Settings=>features=>Text Cursor is still blinking in fact faster then when this setting is on. It also seems to be slower now. 
ConEmu version is 180626 preview

[image]

Comment: A year old build?

Comment: Thanks, that is what I got when installed the latest cmder. Anyway I tried with the latest conemu also 190714. Same issue, probably something to do with windows anyway to troubleshoot?

Comment: When do you observe blinking?

Comment: always, blinking is faster when I switch off blinking in settings.

Comment: @Maximus I finally figured out the reason, I was having JAWS screen reader installed which was interfering. I uninstalled the screen reader which fixed the issue.